# Google Maps JavaScript API with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geolocation

We are using the Google API to get adresses from the autocomplete input.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

The sourcecode can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=de

Now I was wondering if I can get the *longitude* and *latitude* from that request. So we can access an Google Map and calculate the distance from our start-point.

Comment: yes, it's in the response - it'd be `position.geometry.location` in the example -also, with a latitude and longitude of the address, and assuming you have the same for the "start-point" - you don't need google map to calculate the straight line distance - it's just some maths

Comment: @Jaromanda X thanks, alert(position.geometry.location); has no value though. Do I have to use another function?

Comment: see, you've posted ZERO code, so I have no idea where you've put that *alert* call to know if you've done it right

Comment: sorry, looked at the code in google maps example again, and it's `place.geometry.location` you're looking for - I'm surprised that you didn't notice any developer tools console errors, and only said that is "has no value" - I wonder what position even is at that point in the code, would've though it was undefined, therefore you'd get an exception when trying to access position.geometry, let alone postion.geometry.location

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. I figured it out by using     alert(JSON.stringify(place)); in the fillInAddress() function.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is using

**place.geometry.location.lat()** for latitude

**place.geometry.location.lng()** for longtidue

in the fillInAddress() function after declaring the var place.

Thanks @JaromandaX